# How to make a loading animation in Console Application written in C++?

Tags: c++, animation, console, replace, loading

I am coding a Console Application in c++ and I need to make something like a "loading.gif" just by using ASCII characters.

The following is the list of the characters that I should be using:

1. --
2. \
3. |
4. /
5. --

These symbols will make a loading animation by cycling.

However, when I write the output, it become like:

**Output line 1:** --
**Output line 2:** \
**Output line 3:** |
**Output line 4:** /
**Output line 5:** --

I need to do this like this:

**Output line 1:** [this will be replaced all the time]

It should never go to the second line.

How can I do this in C++? Is there any kind of *replace* function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print spinning cursor in a terminal running application using C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199336/print-spinning-cursor-in-a-terminal-running-application-using-c)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the backspace character (`'\b'`) to go back and overwrite characters on the console. You'll also need to flush the output after each change, otherwise the output might stay in a buffer and not appear on the console.

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h> // for sleep()

int main()
{
    std::cout << '-' << std::flush;
    for (;;) {
        sleep(1);
        std::cout << "\b\\" << std::flush;
        sleep(1);
        std::cout << "\b|" << std::flush;
        sleep(1);
        std::cout << "\b/" << std::flush;
        sleep(1);
        std::cout << "\b-" << std::flush;
    }
}
```

Comment: on osx(and possibly *nix/any unicode console) "\b" prints an upside-down ?

Comment: @MatthewClark: That's strange. It works as expected on my Linux bash console.

Answer (score 6):

The Microsoft Windows version.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h> // for sleep()

int main()
{
    std::cout << '-' << std::flush;
    for (;;) {
        Sleep(10);
        std::cout << "\b\\" << std::flush;
        Sleep(10);
        std::cout << "\b|" << std::flush;
        Sleep(10);
        std::cout << "\b/" << std::flush;
        Sleep(10);
        std::cout << "\b-" << std::flush;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Mike Seymour's Logic used but with a realistic look.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h> // for sleep()

int main()
{

    std::cout << "Loading Please Wait";
    while (true)
    {
        sleep(1);
        std::cout << "." << std::flush;
        sleep(1);
        std::cout << "." << std::flush;
        sleep(1);
        std::cout << "." << std::flush;
        sleep(1);
        std::cout << "\b\b\b   \b\b\b" << std::flush;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    for (;;) {

        std::cout << "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bLoading   " << std::flush;
        Sleep(100);
        std::cout << "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bLOading   " << std::flush;
        Sleep(100);
        std::cout << "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bLoAding   " << std::flush;
        Sleep(100);
        std::cout << "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bLoaDing   " << std::flush;
        Sleep(100);
        std::cout << "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bLoadIng   " << std::flush;
        Sleep(100);
        std::cout << "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bLoadiNg   " << std::flush;
        Sleep(100);
        std::cout << "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bLoadinG   " << std::flush;
        Sleep(100);
        std::cout << "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bLoading.  " << std::flush;
        Sleep(100);
        std::cout << "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bLoading.." << std::flush;
        Sleep(100);
        std::cout << "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bLoading..." << std::flush;
        Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Staying very simple, you can use the backspace character, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199336/print-spinning-cursor-in-a-terminal-running-application-using-c), which actually appears to be a duplicate of your question.
For more complicated things, it gets platform specific; to set the cursor position maybe [this can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732292/setting-the-cursor-position-in-a-win32-console-application), if you're on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

And a cross-platform answer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

/* Comment for c++11 solution. */
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /* Uncomment for c++11 solution. */
    // std::chrono::seconds s(1);

    std::cout << '-' << std::flush;
    for (;;) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        std::cout << "\b\\" << std::flush;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        std::cout << "\b|" << std::flush;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        std::cout << "\b/" << std::flush;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        std::cout << "\b-" << std::flush;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that chrono_literals are only available in c++14, you can use `std::chrono::seconds s(1);` instead, passing `s` to `std::thread::sleep_for();`

Answer (score -7):

```
for(i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "Loading: " << i << " %  \n";
    if(i==100)
    {    
        redirect to void or... ?
    }
}
```